# Use data from async function on React State with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm kinda new on React and JS, and I'm having a problem using the data is returned from ASYNC on State and then passing it as JSX. Here is my code:

(PS: I'm receiving from database the data and its working correctly when i console log from the inside function, but I can't seems to find a way using it outside)

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {supabase} from '../db/supabase'
import styled from 'styled-components';
//CSS
const Container = styled.div`
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;`

const RandomQuote = styled.h1`
width: 75%;
font-size: 3.65em;
color: #333;`
export default function App() {
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        getQuotes().then().catch();
    });

    async function getQuotes() {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
            .from('quotes_en')
            .select('quote')
        const getRandomQuote = await data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
        if (error) console.table(error)
        setQuote(getRandomQuote);
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <RandomQuote>{quote}</RandomQuote>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

So the random_quote is returning: `Object quote: "Our life will pass like the traces of a cloud, it will be scattered like mist that is chased by the rays of the sun. For our time is the passing of a shadow. Our lives will run like sparks through the stubble." __proto__: Object` with console.log [Object]

While data is returning: `Array(4) 0: {quote: "Sometimes it takes sadness to know happiness, nois…ppreciate silence, and absence to value presence."} 1: {quote: "If there is no enemy within, the enemy outside can make us no harm."} 2: {quote: "Our life will pass like the traces of a cloud, it …r lives will run like sparks through the stubble."} 3: {quote: "Little by little, day by day, what is meant for you will find its way"} length: 4 __proto__: Array(0)` [Array with Objects]

So can someone firstly explain the problem so I can learn, then sharing a snippet of the updated code would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

All what you need - its just setQuote after getting it from server, inside of `getQuotes`. And use this function in hook [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for first render.

Like this:

```
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState();

    const getQuotes = async() => {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
            .from('quotes_en')
            .select('quote')
        const getRandomQuote = await data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
        if (error) console.table(error)
        setQuote(getRandomQuote); //Here quote goes to state
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      getQuotes().then().catch() //nasty hack for IDE
    }, []);
```

Comment: Error: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: thank you for your anwser, can you check the updated version because your solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved this, but thought I would post for others who may read this in the future. Here is how you would want to use async functions in a useEffect.

```
export default function App() {
    // set initial state to an empty array. Since arrays are immutable
    const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
    
    // your function named 'getQuotes' should return presumably all the quotes
    async function getQuotes() {
        const {data, error} = await supabase
        // return some array of data
        return data ? data : error
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getQuotes()
          // spread the array into the state object. 
          .then(response => setQuotes([...response]))
          .catch(err => err);
    // quotes in dependency array to only run effect when quotes changes 
    }, [quotes]);
   
   // whatever logic you use for getting a single quote from `quotes` 
   const quote = quotes.from(...).select(...)

    return (
        <Container>
            <RandomQuote>{quotes}</RandomQuote>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Why we use this way of updating state when using useEffect

Remember arrays are immutable, so this is how would you update the contents of `quotes` array. If you set to something like setQuotes(response), you will trigger an infinite re-render. See more below.

So, if you do it like this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
     getQuotes().then(response => setQuotes(response)).catch(err => err)
   }, [quotes])
```

Like this you are not spreading response into the default initial array, are creating setting quotes to a completely new array, which causes the state object to update, which re-renders the component, which triggers the useEffect again. Now you have an infinite loop.